# Symfony 4 Login forms security FileLoaderLoadException

Tags: php, symfony

I'm actually in a new Symfony 4 project and I got an Error

> FileLoaderLoadException
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security" (in
> /home/connexio/dev/project/config/packages/security.yaml). Looked for
> namespace "security", found "framework", "doctrine_cache", "doctrine",
> "doctrine_migrations", "twig" in
> /home/connexio/dev/project/config/packages/security.yaml (which is
> loaded in resource
> "/home/connexio/dev/project/config/packages/security.yaml").

I guess that I didn't understand the magic tricks of this tutorial. (The undefined routes leaves me puzzled)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

I precise that I didn't configure my `config/routes.yaml` cause they didn't ask to and I didn't install `FOSUserBundle` cause it's not a symfony 4 bundle.
Instead of that my files are quite the same.

Anyone have an advice to fix it ?

Thanks for reading !

**config/packages/security.yaml**

```
security:
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

**src/Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
<?php  // src/Controller/SecurityController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
    

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error));
    }
}
```

**templates/security/login.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" required autofocus/>

            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            {#
                If you want to control the URL the user
                is redirected to on success (more details below)
                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
            #}

            <button type="submit">login</button>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `security` component. Running `composer req security` should fix your problem.

For further reference check [Symfony 4 documentation - Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html)